# pip3 vs pip issues in building a python wheel

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, python-wheel

I'm trying to build a simple `*.whl` file according to [the docs](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#packaging-python-projects):

```
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade build # <--- success
$ python3 -m build                       # <--- failure 
* Creating virtualenv isolated environment...
* Installing packages in isolated environment... (setuptools>=61.0)
<... omitted for brevity ...>
/tmp/build-env-y4zgw72t/local/bin/python: No module named pip
ERROR Command '['/tmp/build-env-y4zgw72t/local/bin/python', '-Im', 'pip', 'install', '--use-pep517', '--no-warn-script-location', '-r', '/tmp/build-reqs-ioy8d055.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I usually get away with `pip3` instead of `pip` ... until now (?)

---

(`pyproject.toml` file is from the documentation)

Comment: If you don't have dependencies you could try with `python3 -m build --skip-dependency-check`

Comment: This should work without issues. Something might be broken in your Python setup, but there is probably too little info to guess. -- What is the Linux distribution? -- Maybe it is worth installing a Python interpreter from scratch (i.e. not from the Linux distribution's package manager). -- Also read this: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/